# How to pass custom variables into a promise for traceability of what was used to call the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a list of a bunch of addresses I want to geocode. My problem is I want to include a custom property "originalPlaceName" in every response from the promise, so that I have traceability on what I used to pass in originally? Is this possible?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var geocoder = Promise.promisifyAll(require('geocoder'));
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
var inputFile = './myaddresses.txt'
var file = fs.readFileSync(inputFile, "utf8");

var records = parse(file, {columns: true});
var promises = [];
for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var placeName = records[i]['Place Name'];
            promises.push(geocoder.geocodeAsync(placeName));    
}

Promises.all(promises).then(function(result) {
  result.forEach(function(geocodeResponse) {
    // how do I access the original "placeName" variable in here?
  })
}
```

Comment: something like `geocoder.geocodeAsync(placeName).then(result => ({result: result, originalPlaceName: placeName}))`

Comment: So if I have 5 records, it looks like in the Promises.all, the 'origPlaceName' is the same for all 5 responses (whatever was the last placename in the last record)

Comment: if result of geocodeAsync is an object,  `geocoder.geocodeAsync(placeName).then(result => Object.assign(result, {originalPlaceName: placeName}));`

Comment: Yes, I just saw the loop = change `var placeName` to `let placeName`

Comment: Thats it! Please post as answer, I will mark correct.

Comment: well, the code can be considerably neater - will post a full answer with all changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend using array map function rather than forEach with pushing onto an array type stuff - this will simplify the code a bit

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var geocoder = Promise.promisifyAll(require('geocoder'));
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
var inputFile = './myaddresses.txt'
var file = fs.readFileSync(inputFile, "utf8");
var records = parse(file, {columns: true});

// changes start here

Promises.all(records.map(record => {
    let placeName = record['Place Name'];
    return geocoder.geocodeAsync(placeName)
    // add the placeName to the result of geocodeAsync
    .then(result => Object.assign(result, {placeName}));
}))
.then(results => {
    results.forEach(geocodeResponse => {
        // geocodeResponse is each result with the added property:
        // placeName, which is geocodeResponse.placeName
    })
})
```

This will result in just adding `placeName` property to the object resolved by `geocodeAsync`

Alternatively you could do the following

```
Promises.all(records.map(record => {
    let placeName = record['Place Name'];
    return geocoder.geocodeAsync(placeName)
    // add the placeName to the result of geocodeAsync
    .then(result => ({result, placeName}));
}))
.then(results => {
    results.forEach(geocodeResponse => {
        // original geocode result is at  geocodeResponse.result
        // original placeName is at       geocodeResponse.placeName
    })
})
```

Now, each result in the results array will be

```
{
    result: result of geocodeAsync,
    placeName: original place name
}
```

Note: the `Promise.all(...)` code can be further "simplified" to

```
Promises.all(records.map(({'Place Name': placeName}) => geocoder.geocodeAsync(placeName).then(result => Object.assign(result, {placeName}))))
```

and

```
Promises.all(records.map(({'Place Name': placeName}) => geocoder.geocodeAsync(placeName).then(result => ({result, placeName}))))
```

respectively